# Labeling different parts of the body at once

Tags: anatomy

Is there a way to Callout label the anatomy parts of the (i) knee, (ii) lungs, (iii) eyes in one body chart? For purposes of this question, the labels can be "knee", "lungs", and "eyes" respectively.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way: add the labels as you would in `Graphics3D` using the properties `"Name"` and `"RegionCentroid"` as label and position of `Text` primitives:

```
AnatomyPlot3D[{Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftHand"], 
 Blue, FontSize -> 16,
 Text[#["Name"], #["RegionCentroid"], {-1,0}]&/@
 {Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "DistalPhalanxOfLeftThumb"],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "DistalPhalanxOfLeftIndexFinger"]}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, construct a separate `Graphics3D` object for labels and use `Show` to combine it with `AnatomyPlot3D`:

```
 Show[AnatomyPlot3D[{Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftHand"]}], 
 Graphics3D[{ Blue, FontSize -> 16,
   Text[#["Name"], #["RegionCentroid"], {-1, 0}] & /@ 
  {Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "DistalPhalanxOfLeftThumb"],
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "DistalPhalanxOfLeftIndexFinger"]}}]]
```

> same picture